# Describe how to geometrically construct the fth roots of z = i

Tags: complex-analysis

Describe how to geometrically construct the fth roots of z = i

Comment: Note that $i^5=i$, so that $z^5=i$ if and only if $(-i z)^5=1$. Thus, you take the standard fifth roots of unity (which are a pentagon) and rotate them by $-90^\circ$.

Comment: What do you mean by geometrically construct? Do you mean by ruler and compass?